# Why is raised Exception in a try/except block not equal to HTTPError in a method when compared?

Tags: python, error-handling, python-requests, http-error, try-except

- Goal: pass an exception from a try except block to a method to define custom output to the user based on error type without using requests.status_code to specify every error code.
- What I expected: `error == HTTPError` would equate to `True` and not `False`.
- What I've tried: multiple variations from just `HTTPError` to `requests.exceptions.HTTPError` as well as just searching around, on here as well on google, but haven't came across what I was looking for.

When I encounter or raise an `HTTPError` exception and pass the exception as `e` to a method, the argument passed to the method is not equal to `HTTPError`. (I understand its not best practice to `import *` but for testing purposes it simplifies things.)

When I debug it and check the types and equality of exception throughout the program I get the following:

```
e == HTTPError
False

error == HTTPError
False

type(error)
<class 'requests.exceptions.HTTPError'>

type(HTTPError)
<class 'type'>
```

**Code:**

```python
from requests import *


def returnError(error : exceptions) -> dict:
    """ Returns an updated dictionary with corresponding message matching the error """
    if error == HTTPError:
            result = {}
    return result

try:
    raise HTTPError
except (HTTPError) as e:
    returnError(e)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`error == HTTPError` doesn't work because you are trying to compare a class against an instance of said class.

To check if `error` is an `HTTPError`, do `isinstance(error, HTTPError)`.

Comment: That was what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is because `HTTPError` is a class definition but `e` is actually an instance of that class.

Analogous Example -

```py
class Dog:
     def __init__(self):
         pass
```

```py
type(Dog())
>> <class '__main__.Dog'>
```

```py
type(Dog)
>> <class 'type'>
```